# perf report failing with error "data field size is 0 which is unexpected. Was 'perf record' command properly terminated?"

Tags: profiling, perf

I ran perf record with following command:

```
perf record -g -o perf.data.lds "my executables with arguments"
```

Program ran fine and I can see "perf.data.lds" file generated of non-zero size.

```
-rw------- 1 sjain medrd 364855672 Feb 18 12:45 perf.data.lds
```

But when I try to open the perf data using "perf report -i perf.data.lds" command I am getting following error:

```
WARNING: The perf.data.lds file's data size field is 0 which is unexpected.
Was the 'perf record' command properly terminated?
```

Any guidance why this might be happening and how I can resolve this problem will be helpful.

Comment: Did `perf record` print the line `perf record: Captured and wrote`? If not then perf record was not correctly terminated and did not finish the perf.data recording. How did you terminate your program and the perf itself?

Comment: What is the Linux kernel version of the host on which you are running the above experiments ? It looks like that the `perf record` could not populate the header details as it was exiting.

Comment: @osgx I've got the same issue. I couldn't stop the process using ctrl + C so I had to kill -9 it. What should I have done instead?