# How to kill perf record with python subprocess?

Tags: python, performance, monitoring, perf, flamegraph

I am attempting to use the [perf utility](https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html) to monitor my system.

It will be started and killed within a python script. I have created a sandbox like so:

```py
extra_params = ["-F", "99", "-g", "-a", "--"]
record_args = ["sudo", "perf", "record", "-o", "/path/perf.data", *extra_params]
print(f"Starting perf w/ args: {record_args}")
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    args=record_args,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
print(proc.pid)
time.sleep(2)
subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "kill", "-2", str(proc.pid)])
```

This fails to properly kill the process resulting in `perf` not correctly flushing its data. I do not get the `Captured and wrote` success message. Eventually my [Flamegraph](https://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html) states:

```
Unrecognized line: Was the 'perf record' command properly terminated? at stackcollapse-perf.pl line 424, <> line
```

If I open another terminal and run the exact same `sudo kill -2 $pid` command, `perf` exits correctly and the downstream `FlameGraph` executables work correctly.

I have referenced the following resources, all which fail to fix the issue:

- [perf report failing with error "data field size is 0 which is unexpected. Was 'perf record' command properly terminated?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281974/perf-report-failing-with-error-data-field-size-is-0-which-is-unexpected-was-p)
- https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-perf-users/msg08375.html
- https://serverfault.com/questions/967054/how-to-gracefully-kill-linux-perf-tool-process

Thank you!

Comment: I wrote an answer that might be relevant at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76622212/785404