# How can I kill a "perf record" command after a timeout with subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this code:

```py
subprocess.run(['perf', 'record', 'yes'], timeout=1)
```

This code kills the `perf` subprocess after 1 second; however, its child `yes` process is left running.

I expected that this code would behave similarly to running `perf record yes` in a terminal and Ctrl+C'ing it after 1 second. When you do that, the Ctrl+C kills both `perf` and `yes`.

How can I write the code such that both the `perf` child process and the `yes` grandchild process are killed?

Comment: I think this question was previously asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622530/how-to-kill-perf-record-with-python-subprocess, which hasn't received an answer. I think that question does not have a MRE and has a lot of extraneous detail. I decided to re-ask the question in hopes of getting an answer this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this happens because `subprocess.run` calls `Popen.kill` when the timeout expires, which sends a `SIGKILL` signal to the `perf` subprocess. This doesn't give the `perf` process time to do any clean-up, so it leaves its child process running and may also write a malformed output file.

You can instead use `Popen.terminate` to send a `SIGTERM`, which gives the subprocess a chance to terminate.

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(['perf', 'record', 'yes'])
try:
    proc.wait(timeout=1)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    proc.terminate()
```

I'm not aware of a one-liner to achieve this.